# Using a custom ID in a Spring Data REST repository backed by MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm working on a new project using Spring and MongoDB. I'm a novice with both of these so bear with me, I couldn't find a definitive answer to this question.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and have a repository like this:

```kotlin
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "widget", path = "widget")
interface WidgetRepository : MongoRepository<Widget, ObjectId> {
    fun findByType(@Param("type") type: String): List<Widget>
}
```

For an entity like this:

```kotlin
data class Widget @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonProperty val type: String) {
    @Id
    lateinit var id: ObjectId
}
```

This automatically gives you a CRUD API using the Mongo document ID:

```
GET /widget/{mongo doc id}
GET /widget/search/findByType?type=
POST /widget
PUT /widget
PATCH /widget
```

But I don't want to use the Mongo document ID. I want to introduce a secondary identifier and use that everywhere in the API. This is because the "widgets" are items in the physical world that are barcoded, and we don't want to print the Mongo document ID in the barcode.

Obviously we can implement this using Spring REST API tools, eg

```kotlin
    @GetMapping("/widget/{barcode}/")
    fun getByBarcode(@PathVariable barcode: String): Widget {
        return widgetRepository.findByBarcode(barcode)
    }
```

etc.. but is there any clever way to get `@RepositoryRestResource` to build its automagic API for us with a custom ID? Maybe by implementing `CrudRepository<Widget, Barcode>` in such a way that we have to wrap a `MongoRepository<Widget, ObjectId>` ? I'm not familiar enough with how Spring works under the hood to know if anything like this is even possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your Barcode is a unique value for each document, then instead of ObjectId you can use Barcode as your _id. A document's _id value can be of any BSON type (except an array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for an [`EntityLookup`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/support/EntityLookup.html):

> SPI to customize which property of an entity is used as unique identifier and how the entity instance is looked up from the backend.

First - sorry if I make any mistake, I do not use to program in Kotlin - you need to include the `barcode` property in your entity:

```kotlin
data class Widget @JsonCreator constructor(@JsonProperty val type: String, @JsonProperty val barcode: String) {
    @Id
    lateinit var id: ObjectId
}
```

Then, modify your repository and define a new method that will provide a `Widget` given its barcode:

```kotlin
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "widget", path = "widget")
interface WidgetRepository : MongoRepository<Widget, ObjectId> {
    fun findByBarcode(@Param("barcode") barcode: String): Optional<Widget>
    fun findByType(@Param("type") type: String): List<Widget>
}
```

Finally, configure a [`RestRepositoryConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurer.html) and register the `EntityLookup` through an [`EntityLookupRegistrar`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/EntityLookupRegistrar.html):

```kotlin
@Component
class RestRepositoryConfigurator : RepositoryRestConfigurer {
   override fun configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config: RepositoryRestConfiguration) {
       config.withEntityLookup()
          .forRepository(WidgetRepository::class.java)
          .withIdMapping(Widget::barcode)
          .withLookup(WidgetRepository::findByBarcode)
   }
}
```

Please, review the section `15.1` of the [Spring Data Rest documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr) if you need more information.

Comment: @michiakig Did you have the opportunity to test the proposed solution?

Comment: hi thanks for your help, it's working. we had to change `data class Widget` to `open class Widget` as there was an error about `Widget::barcode` being final (kotlin classes are final by default)

Comment: You are welcome @michiakig. I am happy to know that the answer was helpful. And please, sorry for the mistake in the Kotlin class, as I told you, I understand the code when I see it, but I do not use to program in Kotlin

Comment: yes no problem, I was only including that detail for future readers :) thanks again